# Hibernate Delayed Write

Tags: java, hibernate

I am wondering if there is a possibility of hibernate delaying its writes to the DB. I have hibernate configured for mysql. Scenarios I hope to support are `80%` reads and `20%` writes. So I do not want to optimize my writes, I rather have the client wait until the DB has been written to, than to return a bit earlier. My tests currently have 100 client in parallel, the cpu does  sometimes max out. I need this flush method to write to DB immediately and return only when the data is written.

On my client side, I send a write request and then a read request, but the read request sometimes returns null. I suspect hibernate is not writing to db immediately.

```
public final ThreadLocal    session = new ThreadLocal();

public Session currentSession() {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this thread has none yet
    if (s == null || !s.isOpen()) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        // Store it in the ThreadLocal variable
        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}
public synchronized void flush(Object dataStore) throws DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError {
    Transaction txD;
    Session session;
    session = currentSession();
    txD = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(dataStore);
    try {
        txD.commit();
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DidNotSaveRequestSomeRandomError(dataStore, feedbackManager);
    } catch (TransactionException e) {
        log.debug("txD state isActive" + txD.isActive() + " txD is participating" + txD.isParticipating());
        log.debug(e);
    } finally {
        // session.flush();
        txD = null;
        session.close();
    }
    // mySession.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Siddharth Hibernate does not really delay in writing the response , and your code also does not speaks the same. I have also faced similar issue earlier and doubt you might be facing the same that is , when there a numerous request for write into hibernate are there many threads share same instance of your db and even having consecutive commits by hibernate you really dont see any changes .
You may also catch this by simple looking at you MySQL logs during the transaction and see what exactly went wrong !

Comment: Took me some time to debug. Mysql logs are amazing. So these are the results of my debugging. If I

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your hint. Took me some time to debug. Mysql logs are amazing.
This is what I run to check the time stamp on my inserts and mysql writes. mysql logs all db operations in a binlog. To read it we need to use the tool called mysqlbinlog. my.cnf too needs to be `http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpm7%2Fm7enablelogs.html`

I check which is the lastest mysql bin log file, and run this to grep for 1 line above the log, to get the time stamp. Then in java, I call Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilli() to compare with the time stamp.
`sudo mysqlbinlog mysql/mysql-bin.000004 | grep "mystring" -1`

So I debugged my problem. It was a delayed write problem. So I implemented a sync write too instead of all async. In other words the server call wont return until db is flushed for this object.

Comment: I have debugged this further, and found that my mysql bin log is writing into the db "SET TIMESTAMP=1327039370/*!*/; insert into". And my read is happening at "1327039372711" (java new Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMilli()). Seems like my write is happening before my read, but yet the read fails. I am using hibernate "Query rowResult = session.createSQLQuery(rowQuery).addEntity(table.getClass());"

Comment: I am facing same problem, could you please let me know how to change async call to sync in hibernate